# Make <svg> scrollable depending on number of <rect> elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm trying to make my `<svg>` element that contains an unknown amount of `<rect>` elements fill the screen's width, evenly apart and become scrollable on a smaller device, however, despite my `<div>` having an overflow, there's still too much "whitespace" to the right of the elements, how can I remove this and make the `<rect>` elements only use as much space as needed?

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

svg {
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg height="30" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 530 15" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect aria-expanded="false" fill-opacity="1" height="30" width="12" rx="3" ry="3" x="0" y="0"></rect>
    <rect aria-expanded="false" fill-opacity="1" height="30" width="12" rx="3" ry="3" x="0" y="10.25"></rect>
    <rect aria-expanded="false" fill-opacity="1" height="30" width="12" rx="3" ry="3" x="0" y="20.25"></rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Since internal coordinates/dimensions of SVG are relative to it's actual width/height, you'll need calculate and set SVG dimensions based on number rectangles multiplied by rectangle dimension. the `width = "100%"`  will not work.

Answer (score 1):

For this I would use the event wheel and depending on the event.deltax I reset the viewBox of the svg element:

```js
let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
//variable used to reset the value of the viewBox attribute
let Y = 0;

svg.addEventListener("wheel", on_wheel);

function on_wheel(event) {
  //prevent the scroling 
  event.preventDefault();
  Y += event.deltaY;
  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", `-4 ${Y} 20 30`);
}
```

```css
svg {
  border:solid  
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="-4 0 20 30" width="200">
    <rect height="30" width="12" rx="3" ry="3" x="0" y="0"></rect>
    <rect height="30" width="12" rx="3" ry="3" x="0" y="40"></rect>
    <rect height="30" width="12" rx="3" ry="3" x="0" y="80"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure this is what I want? I just see a single, massive `<rect>` rather than 3 rectangles in a row? How would this scale and work with say 50 rectangles in a row on a smaller screen

Comment: Your rectangles are not in a row but in a column one below the other.Your rectangles are overlapping. You wanted to make the svg scrollable. If you scroll over the svg you can see the others rectangles

Comment: That's incorrect, I have them in a horizontal row, thus the `overflow-x` and the `there's still too much "whitespace" to the right of the elements`

Comment: In this case you should to edit your example. In your example -as you have it now - the rectangles have all the same x and different y making it a column